# How can I filter out a specific part of a JSON response in ash shell

Tags: shell, busybox, ash

I'm using wget with -qO to a specific updater URL for OpenELEC which provides the following JSON response, similar to the one below.

```
{"data":{"update":"OpenELEC-RPi2.arm-5.0.8.tar","folder":"releases","host":"","MD5":""}}
```

I only need the full filename of the tar and nothing else.

What is the best way of filtering out all the other non-needed information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) would do:

```
$ jq ".data.update" <<< '{"data":{"update":"OpenELEC-RPi2.arm-5.0.8.tar","folder":"releases","host":"","MD5":""}}'
"OpenELEC-RPi2.arm-5.0.8.tar"
```

or with `-r`:

```
jq -r ".data.update" <<< '{"data":{"update":"OpenELEC-RPi2.arm-5.0.8.tar","folder":"releases","host":"","MD5":""}}'
OpenELEC-RPi2.arm-5.0.8.tar
```

to get the (raw) string without quotes.

Comment: Because OpenELEC is JeOS, it doesn't have jq and I the root file system is read only, so its difficult to add additional packages.

Comment: Well, then jq isn't really a option here...

Comment: Unfortunately not. But useful for other projects.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer as its the correct way to work with JSON data as sed and such has limitations. I was able to compile jq 1.4 with the OpenELEC build system as a static binary.

Comment: Another note OpenELEC doesn't like <<< as its BusyBox, not full bash, instead I echo the JSON response and then piped it to jq to grab the part I wanted.

Comment: I even used to echo it to `jq` before I edited the answer. `<<<` is just used to have the `jq` command in front of the data for readability reasons.

Comment: Absolutely. Just pointing out from the perspective of OpenELEC that the <<< substitution would fail. If the JSON was in a file you could also use jq ".data.update" < jsonfile.json which is pretty clean.

Comment: For OpenELEC users: I submitted a PR to the unofficial addons repo and jq is now available as a console only addon https://github.com/OpenELEC/unofficial-addons/tree/master/addons/tools/jq

Answer (score 1):

As FloHimself said, you should really use a real JSON parser. There are many edge cases that are not easily covered by a simple text processor.

With that caveat:

```
sed 's/.*"update":"\([^"]\+\)".*/\1/'
```

Comment: I agree, jq would be the normal usage case, but the setup of OpenELEC isn't extensible in a usual fashion as other Linux/Unix distros.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you store the JSON in a file called `jsonfile`, then:

```
awk -F "update" '{print $2}' jsonfile | awk -F ":" '{print $2}' | awk -F "," '{ gsub(/"/,"" ); print $1}'
```

Will give as result `OpenELEC-RPi2.arm-5.0.8.tar`.

Keep in mind that it's not an JSON parser, so this will work if you have always the same structure as the example.

Comment: Indeed. Its not ideal using tools not geared towards JSON parsing, but I am limited with the whole JeOS setup, but the JSON response format shouldn't change.

Answer (score 1):

I would have to say - use perl. I'm not 100% sure if that's installed on your OS, but there's quite a good chance it is - it's a pretty common base install component.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;
print decode_json ( <DATA> ) -> {data} -> {update}; 

__DATA__
{"data":{"update":"OpenELEC-RPi2.arm-5.0.8.tar","folder":"releases","host":"","MD5":""}}
```

This would be a 'one liner' by:

```
perl -MJSON -0ne 'print decode_json($_)->{data}->{update}' jsonfile
```

The advantage of doing it this way is that you're using a JSON parser, so it'll work if your json file contains:

```
{"data":{"update":"OpenELEC-RPi2.arm-5.0.8.tar","folder":"releases","host":"","MD5":""}}
```

or

```
{
   "data" : {
      "host" : "",
      "MD5" : "",
      "update" : "OpenELEC-RPi2.arm-5.0.8.tar",
      "folder" : "releases"
   }
}
```

Or some other perfectly valid reformatting of JSON. This is why using a parser is really the ideal way of doing this, because JSON officially doesn't care where your linefeeds go, and allows nesting - and that tends to make regular expressions and line based parsing brittle.

Comment: Just for reference perl is not installed with OpenELEC in the official builds

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`, pipe the output of `wget` to

```
sed -n 's/^.*{"update":"\([^"]*\)".*$/\1/p'
```

This matches the `{"update":` part of the returned string and then extracts the contents in double quotes following the matched part.

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep` with PCRE:

```
grep -Po '(?<=:").*\.tar(?=")'
```

Test:

```
$ foo='{"data":{"update":"OpenELEC-RPi2.arm-5.0.8.tar","folder":"releases","host":"","MD5":""}}'

$ grep -Po '(?<=:").*\.tar(?=")' <<<"$foo"
OpenELEC-RPi2.arm-5.0.8.tar
```